# Transformar HTML em PDF

Tags: html, pdf

Observei que no site do Banco do Brasil é possível escolher o formato de saída de um comprovante de pgto em `txt`, `pdf`, `csv` sem a necessidade de submeter novamente a página.
Existe alguma biblioteca que converta o html exibido na página em PDF sem a necessidade de novo submit e processamento da página?
O back-end será considerado o php ou node.

Comment: Pode ser `JQuery`? Pois se for com PHP, sem sair da página, é impossível (a menos `Ajax`)

Comment: Pode sim. Pensei em usar angular ou jquery. O que você sugere?

Comment: Olá, Já deu uma olhada no dompdf (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) ? Você pode capturar o documento e submeter a um php que faça a conversão.

Comment: Gosto de JQuery (particularmente), respondi...acho que é perfeito pra você

Comment: Eu recomendo usar iText7 e pdfHTML (o mais recente do add-on para o iText7 que lida exatamente o seu caso de uso). Você pode encontrar mais explicação no nosso site em http://itextpdf.com/blog/pdfhtml-introduction

Comment: Muito simples, eu estou usando esta API:
https://htmlparapdf.com.br/como-usar-api.cshtml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

**HTML**

```
<div id="conteudo">
     <h3>Olá, esta é uma tag H3</h3>

    <p>Um parágrafo.</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="btGerarPDF">gerar PDF</button>
```

**JavaScript (JQuery)**

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#btGerarPDF').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#conteudo').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('exemplo-pdf.pdf');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/5r4ra6na/1/)

Comment: ele so redenriza o html ou se colocar algum css ele transforma tbm ?

Comment: Infelizmnte não interpreta o CSS. Mas uma solução simples seria converter o HTML pra Canvas ([exemplo](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)) e ao invés de `pdf.fromHTML()`, usar `pdf.addHTML()`, exemplo: `pdf.addHTML($('#ElementoCanvasQueVoceQuerConverterParaPDF')[0], function () { pdf.save('Teste.pdf'); });`

Comment: Entendi, este metodo `addHTML()` parece ser novo  pelo que vi na documentação, você ja testou ? modifiquei o seu jsfiddle para  ele pra funcionar e apareceu que `pdf.addHTML não e uma função.`

Comment: Ainda não cheguei a testar esta nova função, mas vi por base aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946275/exporting-pdf-with-jspdf-not-rendering-css

Answer (score 3):

Eu já faço uso do *Headless Browser* **PhantomJS** para download de páginas WEB Completas renderizadas de forma FIEL a exibida no browser comum (ele interpreta o JS e CSS) mas com ele tambem é possivel realizar um *print screen* da página desejada da sequinte forma:

- Crie um arquivo com extensão .js
- Cole e salve o seguinte conteúdo:

Comando que acessa uma determinada página e salva o conteúdo da mesma em um .png (mas pode salvar como PDF):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  page.render('stackoverflow.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

- chame-o da seguinte foma na linha de comandos: nome do programa (caso ele tenha sido inserido no path) mais npath do arquivo javascript criado no item acima ficando da seguinte forma:

  phantomjs teste.js

Com ele tambem é possivel estabelecer as dimensões da janela onde o site é exibido (isto é util caso queira ver como está sendo renderizado um site responsivo) da seguinte forma (esta configuração deve ser feita antes do page.open()):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

Você pode chama-lo usando o comando shell_exec desta forma:

```
    $pathToPhantomJS = 'C:\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs';
    $pathToJSScript = 'GetPage.js';
    $comand = $pathToPhantomJS . ' ' . $pathToJSScript . ' ' . $site;
    shell_exec($comand);
```

Obs: passo uma terceira variavel que representa o site a ter sua pagina *printada* o site é pego pelo vetor de args que são passados para o shell.

É possivel criar um CRON JOB para executar o comando `phantomjs teste.js` em determinado horário.

O PhantomJS me foi muito util e é muito configuravel e não conseguiria descrever todas a possibilidades aqui então estou colando alguns links Oficial e não Oficias que poderão ser uteis:

**Download**

Link: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

**Documentação**

Screen Capture: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

viewportSize: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

shell_exec (PHP): [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

1º Faça gerar o pdf por uma instancia de AJAX, no Jquery para ser mais rápido.
2º Execute uma url com o retorno do ajax, contendo o nome do arquivo, em outro
arquivo php o qual ira forçar o download. Desta forma vai ter seu pdf gerado
sem reflesh:

```
<script>

$.get('mypdf.php?id='.$_GET['IDCLIENTE'], function(data){
location.href = 'download.php?file='+data;
});

</script>
```

Para gerar o PDF mais rápido recomendo a biblioteca:
http://html2pdf.fr/en/example.
A mesma basta passar o HTML em uma variavel que ele gera o PDF.

O codigo do PHP do download abaixo:

```
<?php

$file_url = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);

?>
```

Comment: **Colocar dentro da a sua função passando os paramentos o JavaScript/Jquery do meu código.**

Answer (score -3):

Segue código em JS usando a API Html Para PDF:

```js
// Code DEMO here
var settings = {
    "url": "//v1/Consultar?user=<string>&key=<string>&ArquivoID=<string>",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]