# Usar estilo bootstrap para gerar arquivo pdf com php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

Existe algum jeito de se usar o bootstrap para estilizar uma página html que posteriormente será transformada num pdf? Estou usando o plugin mpdf60 no php, e preciso apenas do estilo que o boostrap oferece para usá-lo na exportação de um arquivo pdf.

Considere o seguinte código:

```
    <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Teste PDF</h3></div><div class="col-lg-4"></div></div>
```

Quando eu uso dentro da função $mpdf->WriteHTML(), o estilo do bootstrap não pega, vindo apenas o html, ou qualquer css inline. Usando esse plugin mpdf60 ou qualquer outro, tem algum jeito de eu usar o bootstrap como css?

Comment: Sabe dizer se os arquivos do bootstrap estão sendo carregados de dentro do método `$mpdf->WriteHTML()`? Quando se chama o método `$mpdf->Output()` é gerada uma nova página, os relacionamentos do bootstrap não serão herdados. Faz um teste...

Comment: Não, apenas a página que está gerando o pdf é quem tem o link para os arquivos bootstrap...

Comment: Dentro do método `$mpdf->WriteHTML()` eu utilizo a chamada do css para o pdf através de `<style>` defino todo o css ali, pois absolutamente nada é herdado, vale tentar chamar de dentro do método no `<head>` os links de relacionamento com o bootstrap.

Comment: Entendi, se eu colocasse então o conteúdo css do bootstrap ali dentro (ficaria enorme, eu sei), iria funcionar?

Comment: Provavelmente, mas as bibliotecas PHP/PDF até onde testei não dá suporte a todo o CSS. Na hora da conversão ele "mata" algumas tags e parâmetros, testa aí para a gente saber! =)

Comment: Vale a pena considerar outras opções fora o `mpdf`, como o `phantomjs` e `jsPDF`, veja [essa resposta de Transformar HTML em PDF](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74300/13561), a solução proposta gera um PDF muito fiel ao renderizado na página

Answer (score 4):

Você pode adicionar arquivos css no mpdf para resolver este problema, porém você deve consultar o manual do mpdf para saber se ele suporta todas as configurações do bootstrap: [mPdf Supported CSS](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34)

```
include('mpdf.php');
$mpdf= new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('bootstrap.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```