# Converter View com CSS, JS e Imagens em PDF

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, pdf

Eu tenho uma **view** no Laravel onde carrego vários gráficos. Essa view é composta de HTML, Imagens, CSS e JS.

Eu preciso converter (exportar) essa página em PDF por meio de uma função JS ou PHP.

Eu não consigo achar uma biblioteca que "copie" fielmente a página e a exporte em PDF. A que mais cheguei perto foi o DomPDF, mas bagunça de mais...

Tentei utilizar o **DomPDF** e o **jsPSF**.

Como poderia fazer isso ?

Eu estava dando uma lida nesse post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74300/23919

Mas isso funciona num servidor hospedado ?

Comment: Deve que seu CSS é complexo... e a library não tem suporte para tudo.

Comment: Sim. Por isso quero algo que faça isso fielmente.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada rápida sobre isto.
Dê uma olhada neste link: http://www.mpdf1.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu utilizei o [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), ele tem um uso simples, e renderizei no pdf utilizando inclusive o `bootstrap`, outra opção é o [barryvdh/laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy), gostei menos e é um pouco mais complexo, precisa de um componente instalado no servidor portanto é capaz de não funcionar em certas hospedagens. Eu recomendo o uso do primeiro mencionado, é provável que você tenha que ajustar seu `html` e `css`, mas caso tenha problemas, pode abrir uma nova pergunta mandando o exemplo do código e o erro.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendo usar o mPDF para exportar conteudo html em PDF.
Porém dependendo da complexidade do do html a geração do mesmo pode demorar um pouco, além de consumir muito processamento do servidor.

http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/gerar-pdf-com-php-e-a-biblioteca-mpdf

Answer (score -3):

É muito fácil de consertar, basta usar o caminho absoluto quando estiver prestes a usar o laravel-dompdf.

```
´{{ public_path('img|css') }}  //insted of {{ asset('img|css') }}´
```

Comment: A língua oficial do site é a língua portuguesa, por favor não aqui não publique nada em outra língua a não ser na língua portuguesa. Caso queira publicar em língua inglesa use a versão em inglês do site [so].

Comment: @AugustoVasques Muito obrigado por me lembrar