# Como conveter HTML para PDF em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Eu preciso converter um HTML feito no editor TinyMCE para PDF. Acontece que o texto escrito no editor conterá tags que serão trocadas por valores de registro do banco de dados, como uma mala direta. Consegui fazer isso utilizando HtmlToPDF, porém não renderizava imagem. Mudei para jsPDF, mas ele não renderiza marcações CSS.

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Chegou a olhar [Transformar HTML em PDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74266/91) ?

Comment: veja se isso serve  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119821/como-exportar-uma-div-html-para-pdf-rederizando-o-css